# Delete from a Map with JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
public class ActiveQuest {

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="activeQuest")
    @MapKey(name="task")
    private Map<String, ActiveTask> activeTasks = Maps.createHash();

}

@Entity
public class ActiveTask implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private ActiveQuest activeQuest;

}
```

To delete an `ActiveTask` from an `ActiveQuest` I currently do:

```
final ActiveQuest aq = em.find(....);
aq.getActiveTasks().remove(task);
```

Can I do the same faster (no fetching) with a single JPQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that I don't need to consider the Map at all if I just view it from the side of the task, not the quest.

`DELETE FROM ActiveTask t WHERE t.activeQuest = :quest AND t.task = :taskname`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [JPQL specification](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk) even has some examples

```
 DELETE FROM Publisher pub WHERE pub.revenue > 1000000.0
```